# How can I classify the points by the direction of their vectors?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

There are several figures formed by points. At each point we have two vectors, one pointing to the next point (black) and the other perpendicular to the first one (red). Figures can have any shape and are formed by 3 or more points.

[image: 1]

There are two types of figures: type A, whose red vectors point to the inside of the figure; and type B, whose red vectors point outwards.

what I want is to classify the figures according to where their red vectors point (inside: type A, outside: type B).

For what it's worth, the vectors follow the right hand rule: x = black, y = red, z = coming out of the screen, and they are unitary. And all distances, between one point and the next, are the same.

Thanks you for your time.

Note: what I want is something like a number that, for example, if it is positive then the red vectors point inwards, otherwise they point outwards. And other solutions like algorithms or other mathematics are acceptable.

Comment: See [curve orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_orientation) and the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula).